# How can I automaticaly get data from a googlesheet into a local txt or csv file?

Tags: sqlite, google-sheets-api

I need to automate transfering of data aquired automaticaly in google sheets to a local text or csv or excel file & eventualy into a SQLlite dbase.

Currently I have setup a synched google sheet so that it is also stored at my local computer automaticaly. So that any cloud changes in the sheet would be automatically reflected at a copy in my local computer. Next I need a way to auto tranfer the data in that sheet to an SQLite dbase. My way of aquiring pooled data from cloud to a local database. Any alternative ideas to achieve my goal. I hope I could make this work before June.

I am very sorry for my level of skill. I only know VissualBasic, Pascal & MSDOS batch programming, and a bit of excel manipulation. Zero at API programming.

Comment: You may want to try using Apps Script and any programming language (e.g. Python). Create a script and deploy it as a Web App and let Python run inside a cron job. Here is a [link](https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/03/20/download-files-without-authorization-from-google-drive/) for a tutorial. Hope this helps.